# The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Float Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, widget

Im Coding a homescreen widget in Flutter that should simply display a double value from my app, after following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@ashishgarg1998/how-to-create-home-screen-app-widgets-in-flutter-ce3458f3638e
I created this function in my Flutter Widget, since I only need to update the Homescreen Widget and don't change any values with it.

```
double? yearsLeft = 0.01;
...
Future<void> updateAppWidget() async {
    await HomeWidget.saveWidgetData<double>('yearsLeft', yearsLeft);
    await HomeWidget.updateWidget(
        name: 'HomeScreenWidgetProvider', iOSName: 'HomeScreenWidgetProvider');
}
```

My HomeScreenWidgetProvider.kt looks like this:

```
package com.flutterjunction.homescreen_widget   
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.net.Uri
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundIntent
import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetLaunchIntent
import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetProvider


class HomeScreenWidgetProvider : HomeWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray, widgetData: SharedPreferences) {
        appWidgetIds.forEach { widgetId ->
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {
                
                // Open App on Widget Click
                val pendingIntent = HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity(context,
                        MainActivity::class.java)
                setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent)
                
                val yearsLeft = widgetData.getFloat("yearsLeft", 0) //this is line 22

                var yearsLeftText = "value2 is: $yearsLeft"
                
                

                setTextViewText(R.id.tv_yearsLeft, yearsLeftText)
               


                // Pending intent to update counter on button click
                val backgroundIntent = HomeWidgetBackgroundIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        Uri.parse("myAppWidget://updateyearsLeft"))
                
            }
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the widget_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget_root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_yearsLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="loading..."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I get the following error:

HomeScreenWidgetProvider.kt: (22, 66): The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Float

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

But I have no Idea why?

Comment: Have you tried changing the kotlin version in android build.gradle file, browse for latest kotlin version and paste in build.gradle

Comment: I tried it with version 1.8.10, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Did you mean `val yearsLeft = widgetData.getFloat("yearsLeft", 0f)` ? (or `val yearsLeft = widgetData.getFloat("yearsLeft", 0.0f)` if you want to be more explicit).

Comment: I added the f to the 0, now the error has changed to: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.flutterjunction.homescreen_widget.HomeScreenWidgetProvider: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Float